# JDBC Drivers for SQL Server 2008

Tags: java, eclipse, sql-server-2008, jdbc, sqlconnection

I am trying to connect from a Java app to a SQL Server 2008 database, in Eclipse.  So far I have tried using SQL Explorer and the latest JDBC drivers from Microsoft, but I haven't had any luck so far.  Are there more effective ways of connecting to SQL Server 2008 from a Java app?

Thanks

Comment: What's the issue? Can you provide a stack trace and/or error message from when the error happens. The MS JDBC drivers will work so it sounds like there's a potential configuration error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use [JTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/).

The MS drivers are frankly rubbish. The JTDS ones support Windows Authentication and SSL from non-Windows clients too

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the JDBC-ODBC bridge, connecting to SQL Server as a ODBC source, [JDBC-ODBC Bridge Driver](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/bridge.doc.html), but it is not recommended if you can avoid.

You can try different SQL Server JDBC drivers from third-party, like [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/).

What kind of problems are you facing?

Answer (score 1):

try a generic odbc if you're running your software on windows. you just need to install the odbc windows-driver for your sql 2008 server.